# how to make one button change two stylesheet's

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

hello people of stackoverflow forum.

so on my website I have added the option to change the color on the layout, and I would like to change the header to but i don't know how. the code I am using is in javascript and I am using buttons to change between stylesheets. now my question is how do i go about to make one button changing two stylsheets in one click. the header stylesheet is rather big and i would like it to be separated from the other styling.

**where i got the code:**


-LINK-

---

**javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
     document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href',sheet);
}
</script>
```

---

HTML:

**Head:**

```
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index/index_purple.css" media="screen"/>
```

**Body:**

```
<button onClick="swapStyleSheet('css/index/index_purple.css')">Purple style</button>

<button onClick="swapStyleSheet('css/index/index_orange.css')">Orange style</button>

<button onClick="swapStyleSheet('css/index/index_blue.css')">Blue style</button>

<button onClick="swapStyleSheet('css/index/index_red.css')">Red style</button>
```

---

**My page:**


-LINK-

Comment: _"I would like to change the header"_ - What do you mean by "header"? Do you mean you want to change the text of a particular element?

Comment: the header color. if you go and take a look on my page you would understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason why you do not try to use the command in JS several times?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function swapStyleSheet(pagesheet, headsheet){
        document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href',pagesheet);
        document.getElementById('headstyle').setAttribute('href',headsheet);
    }
</script>
```

The button definition would be

```
<button onClick="swapStyleSheet('css/index/index_purple.css','css/head/head_purple.css')">Purple style</button>
```

Comment: Beacause I don't know javascript yet, im mostly focusing on learning HTML and CSS3 properly. And thanks for the answer it worked (ofc).@Tobias

Comment: No problem :) In Javascript (as in most script languages) you can simply call functions more than once. By ending one command with a semicolon, the parser will wait for the next command...
If the anser helped, you could also accept it ;)

Comment: I must say i was kinda on the track when i was messing around in the code, but I certainly would not have found out of it by myself. again thank you :)

Comment: I guess that is the purpose of the site, so just feel free to ask :)